# What is meant by $B(X,Y)$ and (how) are these theorems equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was hoping someone could explain what is meant by $B(X,Y)$ in the following statement of the Banach-Steinhause theorem (this comes directly from Wikipedia):

Theorem (Uniform Boundedness Principle) Let X be a Banach space and Y be a normed vector space. Suppose that F is a collection of continuous linear operators from X to Y. If for all x in X one has

$\sup\nolimits_{T \in F} \|T(x)\|_Y  < \infty$

then

$\sup\nolimits_{T \in F,\|x\|=1} \|T(x)\|_Y=\sup\nolimits_{T \in F} \|T\|_{B(X,Y)}  < \infty.$

also, it would be nice if someone could help me to understand how/if this statement is equivalent to the following statement (which comes from my course notes)

(Banach-Steinhaus) Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological vector spaces and $\mathcal{L}$ a collection of linear operators in $L(X,Y)$ Suppose that the set of points in $X$ whose orbits $\mathcal{L}x =\{Tx|T\in \mathcal{L}\}$ are bounded in $Y$ is of second category. Then $\mathcal{L}$ is equicontinuous, therefore uniformly bounded. [Note: here $L(X,Y)$ is the space of continuous linear operators from $X\rightarrow Y$]

I think I understand the meaning of the second statement (from my notes), but the first statement (from wikipedia) seems strange and unrelated. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: $B(X, Y)$ is the space of bounded linear mappings $X \to Y$.

Comment: Typically $B(X,Y)$ means the bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. The norm is most likely the obvious one.

Comment: Ok, cool. That was sort of what I figured they meant, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!

Comment: I could still really use some help with the second part though. i.e. (how) are these theorems equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the two version are logically equivalent but the one of your course implies the other one where the assumption is that ALL orbits are bounded.